# PHP foreach insert into same array as it took the data from

Tags: php

I have an array called `$posts` which i ran a foreach on like this

```
foreach ($posts as $post => $content) {

    $find    = array('~\[image="(https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))"\](.*?)\[/image\]~s');
    $replace = array('<img src="$1" alt="" /><p>$2</p>');
    $content = preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);

    }
```

what i need to do now is to save `$content` into the same array at the same index as before, how can i do that?

Note that my array has several fields like Id, Author, content, title & date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass by reference:

```
foreach ($posts as $post =>  & $content) {

    $find    = array('~\[image="(https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))"\](.*?)\[/image\]~s');
    $replace = array('<img src="$1" alt="" /><p>$2</p>');
    $content = preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);

    }
```

Comment: Clever, I would have done: $posts[$post] = $content, but I like this better.

Comment: I output the array inside my view and get 0 difference, it's exactly the same as it is in the database after i added the & before $content.

Comment: @SamPettersson: try doing a `print_r($content);` outside the `foreach`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Returns what's inside the database.

Comment: @SamPettersson: there's a [difference](http://goo.gl/gtpXVF) between the two.

Comment: @AmalMurali note that my array got several fields if i just output it this is the returned array: [{"id":"1","title":"Test","content":"test\n[image=\"http:\/\/google.com\/a.png\"]CAPTION HERE[\/image] ","date":null,"author":null}]

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($post as $post => $content) {
    .... stuff happens here ...
    $posts[$post] = $content;
}
```

The alternative is to use a reference:

```
foreach($post as $post => &$content) {
    ... stuff happens here ...
}
```

but this sort of code is discouraged, because it can lead to very nasty unexpected side effects later if you happen to re-use the `$content` varaible later in the same scope.

Comment: This seems to scramble all the data, the output just becomes "{"